# Pass multiple arrays to JS from PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I have a bunch of data that I'm grabbing in a php file that's set up in several arrrays. Ideally, I'd like to pass all of this to my JS file and then grab each array and output it into a different part of the site. I figured the easiest way would be to push all the arrays into a single array and then grab the specific array inside once the data is passed through ajax.

Here's my PHP

```
$neighborhoodArray();
$areaArray();
$masterArray = array();

// Push info into 2 arrays
while($buildings = mysql_fetch_assoc($allBuildingsQuery)) {
   array_push($neighborhoodArray, $buildings['NEIGHBORHOOD']);
   array_push($areaArray, $buildings['AREA']);
}

while($apartments = mysql_fetch_assoc($allApartmentsQuery)) {
   array_push($neighborhoodArray, $apartments['NEIGHBORHOOD']);
   array_push($areaArray, $apartments['AREA']);
}
```

I'd like to be able to identify each array with a key instead of a number since I'll eventually be adding more stuff to this master array down the line

```
// parseValues is a function I set up to remove empty values and duplicates
$areaValues = array("Area" => parseValues($areaArray));
$neighborhoodValues = array("Neighborhood" => parseValues($neighborhoodArray));

array_push($masterArray, $areaValues);
array_push($masterArray, $neighborhoodValues);

$valuesForOutput = json_encode($masterArray);

echo $valuesForOutput;
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to out put this to specific parts of page through something like this

```
$('.container').html(values.Area);
$('.different-container').html(values.Neighborhood);
```

This is what I have for ajax call

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "procceses/search-values.php?"+url,
datatype: "jsonp",
success: function(values){

  // AreaOnly = values['Area'];
  // AreaOnly = values.Area;

  console.log(values);
    }
});
```

I can't figure out how to navigate the values returned from the PHP file. The response is in the format below. Area and Neighborhood came to be me as objects, but I'd like for them to be arrays that I can iterate through. I also can't figure out how to grab the area and neighborhood objects.

```
[
{
    "Area": {
        "0": "Brooklyn",
        "1": "Bronx",
        "2": "Queens",
        "3": "Out of Area",
        "7": "Manhattan"
    }
},
{
    "Neighborhood": {
        "0": "East Flatbush",
        "1": "Williamsbridge",
        "2": "Cambria Heights",
        "3": "Westchester",
     }
 }
]
```

Comment: What does the console.log() in the success function show? Why do you have `datatype: "jsonp"` when it doesn't look like you're using JSONP.

Comment: Ah I wasn't aware of the difference between jsonp and json. console.log outputs the last bit of info I included up top

Answer (score 0):

By using array_push() the way you do, you area adding an additional layer in your array with a numeric index.

If you want to avoid that, you should fill your array in php like:

```
$masterArray['Area'] = parseValues($areaArray);
// etc.
```

As it is now, your `Area` object is located in:

```
values[0].Area
values[1].Neighborhood
// etc.
```

Comment: Setting up the array like you recommended worked to remove that layer. But for set ups, values[0].Area (original set up) and values.Area (new set up) returns undefined. values however is outputting everything just fine.

Comment: Ah I got it looks, like I had to parse it first (response = $.parseJSON(values);) before accessing it